# Java Google API No Longer Finding Spreadsheets

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets

I'm currently using the Google Spreadsheets API to access a spreadsheet. Here is some code I'm using to establish the credential.

```
try 
{
    InputStream p12 = BotPanel.class.getResourceAsStream("/key.p12");

    File file = new File("hi");
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    IOUtils.copy(p12, outputStream);
    outputStream.close();

    String emailAddress = "81607255786-225dt8i2s8q6qgi0lgg814p27mumqro2@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    String[] SCOPESArray = { "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full", "https://docs.google.com/feeds" };
    final List SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SCOPESArray);
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress).setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file)
                    .build();

    file.delete();
    service = new SpreadsheetService("Test");
    service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
} catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code was working about a week ago, and the way I access the spreadsheets is by using the spreadsheet feed URL. Keep in mind that with this service account I shared a spreadsheet under my own personal account with it so the service account could have access to it. Now, when I try to get the spreadsheet feed I'm getting an empty list. I haven't changed any of the Google drive related code, so if there was an update to the API or something that I'm missing out on, I would be grateful to know what happened.